# generate apache compatible password with mysql

Tags: mysql, apache2, htpasswd, mod-auth-mysql

I am currently in the process of migrating an old webserver.

The old server uses basic auth with users stored in a mysql table and `mod_auth_mysql` enabled.

The password ist stored with apaches build in sha1 function `SELECT sha1('secret')` which works for `mod_auth_mysql`

Unfortunately `mod_auth_mysql` is not supported anymore. That's why I found `mod_authn_dbd` as an alternative.

https://documentation.help/httpd-2.4-es/mod_authn_dbd.html

I alreay managed to get everything up and running until the point that I can login with basic auth and a fixed password

```
<Location />
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Test"
        AuthBasicProvider dbd
        Require valid-user
        AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT '{SHA}qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M=' FROM users WHERE user = %s"
</Location>
```

I only store the sha1 hash in the user table. While the old `mod_auth_mysql` accepted hashes generated by mysql (`SELECT sha1('test')=a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3`) mod_authn_dbd doesn't.

According to https://documentation.help/httpd-2.4-es/password_encryptions.html

> SHA1
> "{SHA}" + Base64-encoded SHA-1 digest of the password.

Passwords generated by htpasswd are accepted.

```
htpasswd -bns user test
user:{SHA}qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M=
```

Now I need to convert this value `a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3` (stored in my db for password test) to `qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M=` (accepted value for password test) inside mysql

I already tried

```
SELECT to_base64(sha1('test')), to_base64(ucase(sha1('test'))), to_base64(lcase(sha1('test')));`
```

but none produces the expected results.

I either need a way to convert my existing password hashes to the expected format or convince `mod_authn_dbd` to accept my existing sha1 hash.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Since you stored the password hash, there should be no way to find the password itself.   What you can do, if you receive a password, is to compare its hash with the one stored, which makes sense.  I read the mod_authn_dbd documentation, and it seems it needs the password to be stored readable.  That's not very wise, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered your own question with the PHP example. The pack() function in PHP converts hexadecimal representations of binary data (which is what SHA-1 hashes are typically displayed as to be human readable) into their original binary (non-human readable) form. You need to run to_base64() against this binary form of the SHA-1 hash you generate like so:

```
mysql> SELECT to_base64(unhex(sha1('test')));
+--------------------------------+
| to_base64(unhex(sha1('test'))) |
+--------------------------------+
| qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M=   |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In this case, you will get the desired output with only MySQL.

Comment: Brilliant. That works. I tried to convert the statement myself but only tried `cast(sha1('test') as BINARY)` and this obviously didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to my question but might be a workaround
I found a blog post where someone ran into the same problem.

http://nileshbansal.blogspot.com/2008/06/password-encryption-mysql-apache-and.html

[image: screenshot]

in the comments there is a link on how to create a htpasswd compatible hash with php. I confirmed that this gives the same result as `htpasswd -bns` command

```php
function sha1_to_htpasswd ( $user, $sha )
{
return $user . ':{SHA}' . base64_encode( pack( "H" . strlen( $sha ), $sha ) );
}
```

If nobody knows a better solution (just mysql and without php) I would propably extend my user table with a column where the password has is stored this way. A bit redundand but it should work.